# jest updates the states but test fails anyway

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have been stuck in writing tests for my Signup component (everything works fine by doing manual testing).

The thing is if I console.log the states into the jest test all of them get updated as they should but the test fails anyway. Can you please help me? Thank you in advance.

signup.test.js

```
    it('changes the state correctly', () => {

        let wrapper = mount(<Signup />);

        const confirmPasswordValidState = wrapper.state('confirmPasswordValid'); // default false

        expect(confirmPasswordValidState).toEqual(false); // it passes

        wrapper = wrapper.update();        
    
        wrapper.find('#password-test').props().onChange({ target: { name: 'password', value: 'maurosorrentino' }});

        wrapper.find('#confirmPassword-test').props().onChange({ target: { name: 'confirmPassword', value: 'maurosorrentino' }});

        wrapper.find('#email-test').props().onChange({ target: { name: 'email', value: 'maurosorrentino@test.com' }});

        wrapper.find('#name-test').props().onChange({ target: { name: 'name', value: 'maurosorrentino' }});

        wrapper = wrapper.update();

        console.log(confirmPasswordValidState); // false why?
        console.log(wrapper.state()); // states change as they should (so in this case is true)
    
        expect(confirmPasswordValidState).toBeTruthy();

    });
```

I get this from my console.logs

```
  console.log
false                                     // console.log(confirmPasswordValidState);

  console.log                             // console.log(wrapper.state())
{
  email: 'maurosorrentino@test.com',
  name: 'maurosorrentino',
  password: 'maurosorrentino',
  confirmPassword: 'maurosorrentino',
  loading: false,
  emailValid: [
    'maurosorrentino@test.com',
    'maurosorrentino',
    'test.',
    'com',
    index: 0,
    input: 'maurosorrentino@test.com',
    groups: undefined
  ],
  passwordValid: true,
  confirmPasswordValid: true,
  nameValid: true,
  formValid: true,
  message: null,
  formErrors: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    name: '',
    confirmPasswordValid: '',
    confirmPassword: ''
  }
}
```

Comment: `wrapper.state('confirmPasswordValid')` gives you the value of that part of the state *at the time you call the method*. If you want to get the possibly-changed value later on, you need to *call the method again*. That's nothing to do with React/Enzyme/Jest, just how JavaScript works. But, more broadly, *don't* make assertions on state - test the component through its public API, don't go messing around with the internals.

Comment: Hi, you just saved me! I thought that since that const just finds the state it was going to update itself automatically when the state changes. Many thanks! I'm not sure what you want to say with "But, more broadly, don't make assertions on state - test the component through its public API, don't go messing around with the internals" can you please explain? Sorry but I'm pretty new to coding and many thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I mean don't write `expect(value from state).toWhatever` - assert on what actually gets *rendered* by the component. I'd recommend use @testing-library, which doesn't expose these implementation details to you at all.

Comment: thank you so much, everything is clear. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrapper.state('confirmPasswordValid') gives you the value of that part of the state at the time you call the method. If you want to get the possibly-changed value later on, you need to call the method again.